Is there a way to restrict overlapping HTML element using Angular material cdkDrag?
Using Angular material CDK drag and drop, i would like to restrict elements overlapping with each other. Similarly to cdkDragBoundary if possible. Is there a built in way to do this?
So i would like to prevent elements being dragged in top of each other like this:


please desribe the question in more detail, like  why cant cdkDragBoundary be used, if possible screenshots highlighting the problem, a working stackblitz would be great to check the issue!
